# Windows Service Crash HPBPRO.dll

Tags: c#, .net, report

I've written and installed a C# Windows Service on a Win 2008 R2 server to manage reports requests.

On service start it add available printers connections:

```
[DllImport("winspool.drv", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]   
[return:MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]   
internal static extern bool AddPrinterConnection(String pszBuffer);
```

Occasionally the service goes down and the only clue i have is the log of the event viewer.

> Faulting application name: CLReportsService.exe, version: 1.0.0.0,
>   time stamp: 0x54774a32 Faulting module name: hpbpro.dll, version:
>   16.2.2.52, time stamp: 0x528514ac Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x0000000000008718 Faulting process id: 0x410 Faulting
>   application start time: 0x01d00ee01a59928c Faulting application path:
>   C:\CoolBiz\CRServices\BancoCarregosa\CLReportsService\CLReportsService.exe
>   Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\hpbpro.dll Report Id:
>   8ec87f50-7ba4-11e4-85d6-b499baa923c9

I can assume that hpbpro for some reason is killing my service and i have search the web for a solution but not come to any conclusion.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cursory Googling has shown that this is part of an HP Printer driver. As far as your p/invoke method looks, it looks fine. The signature and mashalling look fine.

Comment: Have you checked for a newer version of the HP printer driver in question? Also, I'm wondering if maybe that printer driver is not intended for use from a Windows service, only for ordinary programs. Another idea is to see if running the Process Monitor utility from Sysinternals might give you some additional information. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb795533.aspx